# How can I connect a corner of a face to an edge of another face the easiest way?

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges, topology

How can I connect that in the easiest way?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to connect it?

Comment: Because i am worring about light process

Comment: Will you use Eevee or another render engine? As I don't think Cycles or Blender internal will have issues about light (?)

Comment: Yes, i am using Unreal Engine 4

Comment: Well the easiest way would be to subdivide the edge to create a vertex. Slide the vertex to meet the one you are highligthing and then merge them together. You will then get an ngon but its tricky to see from the image you have posted

Answer (score 1):

Add an edge loop (`Ctrl + R`) to the main object aligned with the vertex then merge them (`Alt + M`). You can also merge them at center, at the position of the first one or the second one. After that, you can merge the other vertices to reduce the number of triangles...

[image: edge]

[image: 2ndedge]

[image: 3rdstep]